# How to dynamic change template in Jquery fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have done a script in jQuery which allows multiple file uploads for image gallery. Everything works fine except for the progress bar. The problem is that it has two colors yellow - when uploading (add), green - when uploaded (done) - is should change into green after the file is uploaded (finished) and at the moment it automatically changes all pictures status into green when the first of the files has been successfuly uploaded. Can anyone have a look at the code and give me some suggestions what is wrong?
Thanks in advance for any advices.

```
$(function(){
    var ul = $('#upload ul');

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({
        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        // dropZone: $('#drop'),
        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        dataType: "json",
        url: "upload.php",
        limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
        sequentialUploads: true,
        bitrateInterval: 1000,

        add: function (e, data) {
            var tpl = $('<div class="upload_progress" style="padding: 20px 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><div style="float: left;"><img src="http://www.koga-kotwica.rcez.pl/admin/images/empty.jpg"></div><div><span></span><p></p><div class="progress progress-bar-striped active"><div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div></div></div>');
            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(".upload_photo");
            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },
        progress: function(e, data){
            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            data.context.find('.progress-bar').width(progress +'%');
            console.log(data.bitrate);
        },
        done:function(e, data){
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                // Append the file name and file size
                //data.context.find('.progress-bar').width('0%');
                $('.upload_progress').removeClass('upload_progress').addClass('upload_done');
                data.context.find('.progress').css("display","none");
                //data.context.find('.progress').toggleClass("progress-bar-success");
                data.context.find('p').text("Plik został przesłany poprawnie !!!");
                data.context.find('span').text("Nazwa pliku: " + data.files[0].name + " ") 
                     .append('</br> Rozmiar: ' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size));
                data.context.find('img').attr("src", "photos/"+data.files[0].name).css(
                    {'width' : '130px', 'padding': '0px 10px'}
                ); 
            });
        },
        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }
    });

    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }
        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }
        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }
        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }
});
```